# GNU/Linux-based alternative to AD CS

Tags: gratis, server

Are there any free, GNU/Linux-based, alternatives to Microsoft's Active Directory Certificate Services? I have already migrated Active Directory from Windows Server to SAMBA4 but have yet to find a good alternative to AD CS, specifically I need AD integration and web enrollment (with AD integrated authentication)

Thank you for your time and help!